# How to schedule the execution of classes in testng.xml file?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

Within a single package I have multiple classes . But how to schedule the execution of classes one after another in testng .
My testng.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="AutomationTestWrangler">

<test name="Smoke Testcases">
    <classes>
        <class name="DataWrangler.LoginResigterComponents"/>
        <class name="DataWrangler.Register"/>
        <class name="DataWrangler.Login"/> 
        <class name="DataWrangler.Dashboard"/>
    </classes>
</test>

</suite>
```

But execution is happening in the following order.My testng output is coming in following order

```
DataWrangler.Register
DataWrangler.Login
DataWrangler.LoginResigterComponents
```

how to make execution schedule

```
DataWrangler.LoginResigterComponents
DataWrangler.Register
DataWrangler.Login
```

Comment: Hi Sidhartha, there is nothing wrong with your xml! Are you sure the execution is happening in the order you are proposing?

Answer (score 1):

I've faced same issue before few days.I found problematic code was, I'd prioritize some test method in different classes. When i execute all my classes from `testing.xml` it was executing prioritized method class first. So this could be the problem in your case.

I have few guidelines here -

1. If your requirement is to execute bunch of classes using `xml` then better dependencies of test methods in your classes.
2. Use `priority` in your test methods carefully. If you have assigned same priority for two different test methods of different classes and executing your code using `xml` file then first priority test method will execute first no matter what order you have maintained in `xml` file.

The another alternative solution you can try is add `group-by-instances="true"` in you `<test>` tag  of `xml` file

e.g.-

```
<test name="parallel-running-test" group-by-instances="true">
```

**Updated :-** This is how priority works

**class 1**

```
public class MyFirstClassTest {

@Test(priority = 2)
public void myFirstClassTestOne(){
    System.out.println("myFirstClassTestOne");
}

@Test (priority = 2)
public void myFirstClassTestTwo(){
    System.out.println("myFirstClassTestTwo");
}

}
```

**class 2**

```
public class MySecondClassTest {


@Test(priority=1)
public void mySecondClassTestTwo(){
    System.out.println("mySecondClassTestTwo");
}

}
```

**`Testing.xml`**

```
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" thread-count="2" >

<test name="parallel-running-test" >

    <classes>
        <class name="test.abc.MyFirstClassTest"/>
        <class name="test.abc.MySecondClassTest"/>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Result

[image]

Comment: @Xwris Stoixeia , Thanks for reply. are you sure priority can't do this kind of thing. I am updating my question have a look

Answer (score 0):

In your testng.xml you have to define:

```
<groups>
    <dependencies>
      <group name="a" />
      <group name="b" depends-on="a" />
      <group name="c" depends-on="a b" />
    </dependencies>
  </groups>
```

Annotate your test classes as following:

```
@Test(groups = {"a"})
public class LoginResigterComponents

@Test(groups = {"b"})
public class Register

@Test(groups = {"c"})
public class Login
```

Alternatively you can set up dependencies with annotations only:

```
@Test(groups = {"a"})
    public class LoginResigterComponents

    @Test(groups = {"b"}, dependsOnGroups = {"a"})
    public class Register

    @Test(groups = {"c"}, dependsOnGroups = {"a b"})
    public class Login
```

**Update**

Alternatively try adding `preserve-order` attribute:

```
<test name="Smoke Testcases" preserve-order="true">
```

Comment: By using "@Test(groups = {"a"})
    public class LoginResigterComponents

    @Test(groups = {"b"}, dependsOnGroups = {"a"})
    public class Register

    @Test(groups = {"c"}, dependsOnGroups = {"a b"})
    public class Login " this technique if the any testcase fails in the previous class the next class is not executing .And "<test name="Smoke Testcases" preserve-order="true">" is not working .

Comment: Add this @Test(groups = {"c"}, alwaysRun = "true") to your annotations

Comment: I'm not getting this 100% @Maciej - Does alwaysRun=true defy the purpose of groups?